# ImageIcon doesn't appear in JFrame window

Tags: java, swing, jframe, imageicon

I was testing adding `ImageIcon` to `JLabel`, then `JLabel` to `JFrame`, but it doesn't work. I mean, the image doesn't appear. It also doesn't throw any exception. The code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Tests {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ImageIcon c = new ImageIcon("BlackBishop.png");

        JLabel b = new JLabel();
        b.setIcon(c);
        b.setSize(400,400);

        JFrame a = new JFrame();
        a.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        a.setSize(500,500);
        a.setVisible(true);
        a.add(b);

        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

How can I make image appear?

Comment: 1) Use `ImageIO` to read the image file. You will get an error message is the image can't be read. 2) Components must be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible.

Comment: `ImageIcon(String)` will assume that the file is located relative to the "work directory".  In general, a better solution is to "embedded" the resources so they can be bundled with your jar file and it makes it easier to load in the long run.  Also, like everyone else, use `ImageIO`